# How to build an iterative user-defined action in Visual Build Professional?

Tags: build-process, build-automation, extensibility, visual-build-professional

In VBP its possible to define user defined actions by creating a custom COM component or a custom script.

I need to create an user defined action which is *iterative*, which means it has to call child steps in an iterative manner like the "process files" built in action does.

I can't figure out how to do this and Google isn't helpful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself on the [kinook forums](http://www.kinook.com/Forum/showthread.php?s=fb5c520b09c9816440e0f8a796f5d9e1&threadid=535&highlight=user+defined+action):

Its not possible to define an iterative user-defined action, but its possible to use a workaround by defining a conditional build rule in the loop controlling step.